# "you will" vs "will you"

Tags: sentence-construction

Which sentence is Correct Among both

1. How much will you pay for me
2. How you will pay for me

Answer (score 0):

"How much" is asking for a quantity. "How" by itself is asking for a means or method.

Example 1:

> How much will you pay for me?
>
> I'd pay up to $20.

Example 2:

> How will you pay for me?
>
> I'll pay with a credit card.

By the way, both sentences sound, at least taken out of context, like the speaker is asking the person about buying him or her, like you would buy a slave or a prostitute. Perhaps the intent is that they are asking about buying something on behalf of him or her?